# How to get the Java Output screen?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to display images on the screen using Graphics but the screen doesn't load

The output screen appears but only show The black screen and not the images

The code gets compiled properly so why am i not getting the output

```
package game;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Screen {
    private GraphicsDevice vc;

    public Screen(){
       GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
       vc=env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    }

    public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window){
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);

        if(dm !=null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
            try{
                vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
            }catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }

    public Window getFullSCreenWindow(){
        return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    }

    public void resotreScreen(){
        Window w= vc.getFullScreenWindow();
        if(w!=null){
            w.dispose();
        }
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(null );
    }


}



package game;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

class Images extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800,600,16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);

       Images i = new Images();
       i.run(dm);

    }

    private Screen s;
    private Image bg;
    private Image pic;
    private boolean loaded;
    public void run(DisplayMode dm){
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,24));

        loaded =false;

        s = new Screen();

        try{
            s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
            loadpics();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }catch(Exception ex){}
        }finally{
               s.resotreScreen();
        }

    }

    public void loadpics(){
        bg = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Dhruv\\Downloads\\Ronaldo.jpg").getImage();
        pic =new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Dhruv\\Downloads\\Messi.jpg").getImage();

        loaded= true;
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if(g instanceof Graphics2D){
            Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }

        if(loaded){
            g.drawImage(bg,0,0,null);
            g.drawImage(pic,170,180,null);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting should be done in Swing. Hint, don't override `paint` of top level containers

Comment: `Thread.sleep(10000);` is pointless, as it has the capacity to stop the UI from been painted.

Comment: My suggest is, don't worry about full screen mode, get it to work with a normal window first, then implement the full screen support

Comment: I'm kind of weird out by people voting to close this as not providing a runnable example, has anyone actually copied the code to an IDE and tried running it?  I mean, it compiles for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with background information...

A `JFrame` is a container for a `JRootPane`, which contains the `contentPane`, `JMenuBar` and `JGlassPane`

[image: RootPane]

When you override `paint` of top level container like `JFrame`, you are only painting the bottom most component, the `JRootPane` and it's contents are then painted over the top, making it kind of pointless.

See [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details

Painting is also a complex operation, failing to call `super.paint` will cause no end of issues, make sure you always call the super paint method before painting unless you really understand how it works and are prepared to do it's job manually.

In Swing you are instead encouraged to extend from a `JComponent` based class (`JPanel` been the preferred) and override its `paintComponent` method and perform your custom paint there

This component can either be added to the window or set as the `contentPane` or added to some other container depending on your needs.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

`ImageIcon` uses background thread to load it's images, so even though it returns, the image might not be realised (or fully loaded).  When you use `g.drawImage(bg,0,0,null);`, passing `null` as the `ImageObserver`, it prevents the container from knowing when the image changes and allowing it to automatically repaint itself.

What's cool is, all `Component` based classes implement `ImageObserver`, so pretty much anything which can paint can act as an `ImageObserver`.

Convention would encourage to pass `this` as the `ImageObserver`.

Generally, a better solution is to use `ImageIO`, which when it loads images, won't return until the image is fully realised.

Have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

`Thread.sleep(10000);` is a dangerous thing to use in Swing.  It has the potential to stop the UI from been updated or respond to other input and events, making your program appear as if it's hung, because it has.  But in your case, it means you're violating the single thread rules of Swing.

Swing is a single threaded environment, you should never perform any action which might block the Event Dispatching Thread and you should never update the UI from outside the context of the EDT.

There are solutions available to help you, Swing `Timer` for generating periodical events which are dispatched within the EDT and `SwingWorker` for performing long running operations which have support for updating the UI.

See [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for more details.

My recommendation is to not worry about the full screen support, focus on getting the images painting using a normal window and the add the full screen support.  This allows you to solve problems within an isolated set of functionality, making it much easier to solve.

Comment: Oh what a surprise, yet another unsolicited downvote, seen as no new answers have been provided and no new downvotes or close votes have been made against the question, I can only assume you have a personal dislike of me, unless you can provide some assistance as to why you might find my answers objectical, nothing is going to change