# The code for home screen (to develop 2d-games) is throwing the following compile time errors

Tags: java, swing, 2d-games

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:  
    The method setBackgroundColor(Color) is undefined for the type App  
    The method setForegroungColor(Color) is undefined for the type App   
    The method setFontSize(Font) is undefined for the type App  
    window cannot be resolved to a variable  
    The method restoreScreen() is undefined for the type Screen
```

---

```
    import java.awt.DisplayMode;
    import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
    import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
    import java.awt.Window;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Screen {
                private GraphicsDevice vc;

    public Screen(){
        GraphicsEnvironment env= GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        vc= env.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    }
        public Window setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm,JFrame window){
            window.setUndecorated(true);
            window.setResizable(false);
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);

            if(dm!=null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
                try{
                    vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
            public Window getFullScreenWindow(){
                return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
            }

            public void restoreScreen(){
                Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
                    if(w !=null){
                        w.dispose();
                    }
                    vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DisplayMode dm= new DisplayMode(800,600,15, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
        App var= new App();
        var.run(dm);
    }   

        public void run(DisplayMode dm){
            setBackgroundColor(Color.PINK);
            setForegroungColor(Color.WHITE);
            setFontSize(new Font("ARIAL", Font.PLAIN, 24));

            Screen s= new Screen();

            try{
                s.setFullScreen(dm, window);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
            finally{
                s.restoreScreen();
            }

        }
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.drawString("this is cool", 200, 200);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ******///////********///******/////***** - Does it mean another file?

Comment: Maybe it should be dm.setBackgroundColor()? From where is this method? I, and as the compiler, don't see the implementation of the method

Comment: You should describe your problem more in the body and use the title as a summary of your question.

Comment: Michel_T:yes..it is another file

Comment: Tip, add @Michel_T. or whoever you want to notify of a reply (The `@` is important). Also, use a consistent indenting format, it will make it easier to follow the flow of the program

Comment: Your first example is declaring methods within methods, your second example doesn't extend from anything which defines the methods you're trying to call

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating an object called window anywhere in your code.

You can update your `App` class to extend `JFrame` and then pass that into the line `s.setFullScreen(dm, window);`. You would also need to correct the method names of `setBackgroundColor`, `setForegroundColor` and `setFontSize` as shown in the updated example below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class App extends JFrame{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    DisplayMode dm= new DisplayMode(800,600,15, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    App var= new App();
    var.run(dm);
  }

  public void run(DisplayMode dm){

    this.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setFont(new Font("ARIAL", Font.PLAIN, 24));

    Screen s= new Screen();

    try{
      s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
      try{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      }
      catch(Exception e){

      }
    }
    finally{
      s.restoreScreen();
    }

  }
  public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("this is cool", 200, 200);
  }
}
```

This shows a pink screen with white text for 5 seconds, which I think is your intention

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't extend JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252329/java-swing-using-extends-jframe-vs-calling-it-inside-of-class) and instead create an instance of it.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: App.main(App.java:11).....still throwing this error

Comment: [This is why you don't extend from `JFrame` AND override `paint`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868437/how-to-get-the-java-output-screen/41868837#41868837), please, I'm tried of fixing these types of bad recommendations, please stop suggesting them